# Vector .docx to vector .pdf?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, images, vector-graphics

I use Word 365 (16.0.12130.20272 64-bit) on Windows 10 x86_64. When I add an *.svg* vector graphic image eg. via drag 'n drop, or an *.emf* vector graphic image via eg. Insert->Pictures, Word stores the image in a vector graphic way, no problem. Although, I couldn't find any way to export the Word document to PDF format which would keep the vector graphic image instead of replacing it with a raster image placeholder. Tried using *High fidelity* compression for the images and tried all the PDF export option combinations, nothing worked for me. Opened the PDF documents with Adobe Reader DC and Google Chrome, bad results with both of them.

Do any of you have experience with this issue? Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How are you saving them as PDF? First thing is not to use the built in image compression too as that will probably convert it to jpeg.

Comment: File > Export > Create PDF/XPS > (at this point I tried each and every setting combinations with the checkboxes)

Comment: I had success creating vector graphic PDF with this tool: [doPDF](http://dopdf.com/download.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured it out. As it seems neither my *.svg* or *.emf* files were purely vector graphic images. I had a raster image inside the files embedded next to the vector graphic content.

It is also a problem for Word if you have raster image next to the vector graphic image on the same Word document page or in the header.

By removing ALL the raster images from the page, the PDF document is generated with vector graphic image. It is a shame though that if the *.svg* contains gradient colors Word transforms the vector graphic image to raster image.

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 has just lately added support for SVG, and evidently not in a complete
manner.

I suggest installing Acrobat Reader. This will create an "ACROBAT" tab in word,
that contains the action "Create PDF". Using Adobe to create the PDF should
work better.

Comment: I think Adobe removed the free component from Adobe Reader DC and transformed it into a subscription based cloud service.

Comment: I can confirm that this functionality has sadly been removed from the latest version of Acrobat Reader. Although Word 365 ships with a built in virtual PDF printer.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used SVG files much, but this sounds similar to an issue I had with EPS/PDF files. My graphics do contain a combination of bitmap images in them + vector graphics. You could check if **[import the SVG, and print/save the Word document to PDF prior to saving the document](https://superuser.com/questions/1713351/how-to-stop-word-from-rasterizing-imported-vector-graphics/1713352#1713352)** works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Bot Delete it then. The answer contains the complete algorithm suspected to solve the issue, and it links to another question/answer with more complete background. There is no need to duplicate all the details.