# How to stop Word from rasterizing imported vector graphics?

Tags: microsoft-word, compression, vector-graphics

I have various vector graphic images in PDF or EPS form (EPS is now [only usable on Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/support-for-eps-images-has-been-turned-off-in-office-a069d664-4bcf-415e-a1b5-cbb0c334a840) though), and they often contain embedded bitmap images and/or transparency.

When I import them into MS Word, they become rasterized (bitmapped) with a significant reduction in quality. But I need to print/save to PDF in high quality, preserving the vector graphic information (lines, scalable text, etc.). The solution of "[opening the PDFs in Preview and exporting as a bitmap. Then you can control the resolution and get a better-looking result](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/poor-image-quality-in-word/0d36296e-0321-4842-abcd-8c9f774125d8)" does not preserve this scalability. **How can I stop Word from ruining my graphics?**

---

Research notes:

MacOS 10.14.6 with Word 16.54, but I think the issue is common to multiple versions based on some of the links below.

This question is very similar to [How to stop Word from downsampling images](https://superuser.com/questions/1661685/how-to-stop-word-from-downsampling-images), but the annoying thing this time is rasterizing, not downsampling.

Adobe Illustrator acts like it can export as [EMF](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/emf-image-file-imports-larger-than-original/c20d9ba7-92d5-41eb-9966-0d667b85fb27), which is supposedly a [vector format](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/poor-image-quality-in-word/0d36296e-0321-4842-abcd-8c9f774125d8), but the resulting file is practically unreadable on the Mac and does not solve the issue in Word (text characters were garbled).

[Word compresses images by default](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-1538-compresses-images-by-default/f8ff46cd-e238-4ce3-9e87-e7b9fc4881ff). Word for Windows has a "[do not compress images in file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-off-picture-compression-81a6b603-0266-4451-b08e-fc1bf58da658)" option (which I am skeptical would help in the vector graphics case). But I need a different solution for Mac, because the "do not compress" option simply does not appear in the Preferences dialog on Mac. Some of Word's compression behavior can supposedly be controlled by a [registry DWORD](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/automaticpicturecompressiondefault-in-office-2019/a6ee9e02-91e1-49a3-85fb-dcf455dd35a6) on Windows, but when I tried to guess at an equivalent parameter that works in com.microsoft.Office365V2.[plist](https://staxmanade.com/2015/02/mac-equivalent-of-the-windows-registry---ish/) on the Mac, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is that the compression (or rasterization) happens on [Save](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/office-docuemnt-image-quality-loss). So the workaround is to **import the PDF, and print/save to PDF prior to saving the document.**

---

There are a couple of bonus tricks. I'm not sure if it helped, but I did turn off all the image compression I could find:

[image]

But what definitely helped was turning off all the autosave, as I discovered by importing one vector graphic, importing a second one, saving to PDF, and seeing that the first one had already been degraded even though I never saved the document between importing the two graphics. An autosave operation had kicked in and ruined my graphics in the background.

[image]

I am praying that Microsoft doesn't see this post and decide to "fix the bug" so that images are compressed/rasterized on import, rather than on save.

---

Remember to turn autosave back on if you need it.